Moving videos to from Android phone to Win11 laptop gone wrong
This one is still baffling me, I'm hoping maybe someone else had a similar experience or may have an explanation.
I ran out of storage space on my Samsung Galaxy S22 and figured I'd move the top 30 longest videos from my device to my laptop that's running Win11.
Steps I took:

Enable developer mode
Connect phone by choosing MTP mode for transferring files
Copied said 30 videos to my laptop using Windows Explorer, on J:\videos
Opened a few files from the new location on my laptop to check that copying went well
Deleted the said 30 videos from my phone from Windows Explorer
Eject USB device from Windows

This is where it got weird. As soon as I ejected the phone from Windows, I get a a pop-up message error on my laptop saying the new location J:\videos is not accessible anymore, it was either moved or deleted. As I click OK on the popup, I see the folder disappearing from explorer. I have no idea what I did wrong.
I installed Recuva file recovery and also Windows' file recovery command to see if I can recover anything. What both detected was a folder called J:\New folder with exactly the 30 files I had moved to my laptop. Recovering them however did not work, every single mp4 video is corrupted and cannot be opened by any video player.
Does anyone recognize this as being a user error (if so, what should I have done different), Android related or Win11 related?
Thank you.
-- Edit
One more important detail to mention is that recovered files, although corrupted, take up the exact same amount of disk space that I now have free on my phone, so I don't think I made shortcuts on disk by mistake.

What file-system is used by your J: drive (FAT32, exFAT, NTFS, ..)? Developer mode is not necessary for MTP. It is only necessary if you want to use adb (drivers and adb installation required on PC side).

File system is NTFS
